# Web application logs out automatically when clicked on button in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angular-ui-router

I have an web application where we show a set of values on UI which has button named 'view schedule'. When clicked on 'view schedule' button, we make a redirection to viewSchedule controller which shows the ui-grid tables.

The issue is that when clicked on 'view schedule' button, the web application logs out automatically and redirected to login page.

Why routing to login page is because in app.js file, routing is made to login page in urlRouterProvider if no route is found.

I have pasted the code below:

**app.js**

```
    angular.module('app').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, IdleProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
}]);
```

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tm view-plan-btn" ng-click='approval.viewSchedule()'>View
        Schedule
        </button>
    </div>
```

**Controller** :

```
me.viewSchedule = function() {
            toastr.clear();
            var url = $state.href('fullview.viewSchedule', {
                id: campaign.campaignId
            });
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        };
```

Comment: Where do you have the routing mapped for viewSchedule. I think as it is not found, it takes you to the default routing which is the /login

Comment: @CrazyMac : Thanks for the reply

var viewSchedule = {
            name: 'fullview.viewSchedule',
            url: '/campaign/:id/viewSchedule',
            templateUrl: 'src/skynet/campaign_schedule/view/viewSchedule.html',
            controller: 'viewScheduleController',
            cache : false
        };

$stateProvider..state(viewSchedule);

Mapping is given in stateProvider of config file.

Comment: Are you sure the calling URL pattern and the mapping is same. Please dump the calling URL pattern and compare it against your mapping

Comment: please add your route configuration to the question.